# Using htaccess to redirect URL from one query string to another

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, phpbb3, mybb

I need to redirect

from

```
/showthread.php?tid=6
```

to

```
/viewtopic.php?t=6
```

using htaccess. We moved from MyBB to PhpBB and would like to safe links leading to our site.

The domain remains the same. All my attempts failed.

Can someone help?

Comment: Let me know if my answer below works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^showthread.php?tid=(\d+)$ viewtopic.php?t=$1
```

This should do the trick with htaccess redirect parameter :)